# Centralized place to access response Context-Length for telemetry

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, azure-application-insights, asp.net-core-middleware

I want to add telemetry either as a log or to Application insights for the Content-Length of a response in dotnet core 2.2. I've tried a number of places in middleware and different filters in the request pipeline. No where that I've checked has the Content-Length materialized--it's always null.

My alternate solution was to check the response stream myself and compute the length but I'd really prefer not to re-read the stream if I don't have to. Is there somewhere in the dotnet core request pipeline that I can hook into for that information?

Answer (score 1):

You will still have to implement custom middleware for this. Here is an example:

```
public class CustomMiddleware
{
    private readonly RequestDelegate _next;
    public CustomMiddleware(RequestDelegate next)
    {
        _next = next;
    }

    public async Task InvokeAsync(HttpContext context)
    {
        // store original response and replace it with another
        var originalResponse = context.Response.Body;
        
        await using var newResponse = new MemoryStream();
        context.Response.Body = newResponse;
            
        
        await _next(context);

        // You can easily access Length property of the stream here
        // and log it (logging skipped in the example)
        var contentLength = newResponse.Length;

        // setting back the original stream
        newResponse.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
        await newResponse.CopyToAsync(originalResponse);
        context.Response.Body = originalResponse;
    }
}
```

You can also see this [implementation](https://github.com/aspnet/BasicMiddleware/blob/master/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Buffering/ResponseBufferingMiddleware.cs), which uses buffering

Comment: That's exactly what I came up with on my own but I don't like the performance implications of the `CopyToAsync`. I'm really hoping I can just access that header somewhere in the pipeline.

Comment: Seems like this is not possible. Even the `Http logging` middleware uses similar approach in here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/http-logging/?view=aspnetcore-6.0

Is says: "Response Body. Logging the response body has performance implications, as it requires buffering the entire response body up to HttpLoggingOptions.ResponseBodyLogLimit."